# Trim words but stop at end of html element if found

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-split

This function works great however if an html element is found it will stop where the 45th character count is no matter what, which breaks the html element. How can I make an exception for this? I'm guessing some kind of regex but not sure what is best in this case.

```
public function fts_custom_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 45, $more ) {
    ! empty( $num_words ) && 0 !== $num_words ? $more = __( '...' ) : '';
    $text = nl2br( $text );
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    // Add tags that you don't want stripped.
    $text        = strip_tags( $text, '<strong><br><em><i><a>' );
    $words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $num_words + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
    $sep         = ' ';
    if ( count( $words_array ) > $num_words ) {
        array_pop( $words_array );
        $text_string = implode( $sep, $words_array );
        $text        = $text_string . $more;
    } else {
        $text = implode( $sep, $words_array );
    }

    return wpautop( $text );
}
```

Right now it will break something like this....

@aeocreative and I at the Sarasota Magazine "Home of the Year" awards! I photographed a home for @tracee_murphy of < a 
href="https://www.instagram.com/trade"...

Comment: Are you wanting the link to be clickable or plain text after the strip?

Comment: What does the string start as, and what should it finish as?

Comment: I was hoping for if it finds an html element that it will wait till the end of it before adding the ...

Comment: Maybe something like https://regex101.com/r/KxyVTT/1/ That should skip elements, with some exceptions, and might skip some chemical formulas and math equations but presuming that is all right?

Comment: The string is dynamic and could contain any number of links, so ideally I need something for if it finds a link before stopping make sure to include the rest of the link before stopping... I have seen tons of so called solutions but none are working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work, untested, but it should work, and do what you asked...

this first one is to truncate @ number of characters

```
<?php

function truncate_by_characters ( $s, $l = 45, $e = '...' )
{
    $sl = strlen ( $s );

    $ns = 0;

    $cr = 0;

    $rs = '';

    preg_match_all ( '/<[^>]*>[^<]+<\/[^>]*>|<(?!\/)[^>]*>/', $s, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER );

    foreach ( $m as $v )
    {
        if ( ( $v[0][1] - $ns ) >= $l )
        {
            break;
        }

        $ss = substr ( $s, $ns, ( $v[0][1] - $ns ) );

        $cr += strlen ( $ss );

        $rs .= $ss . $v[0][0];

        $ns = ( $v[0][1] + strlen ( $v[0][0] ) );
    }

    if ( $cr < $l )
    {
        if ( ( $ns + ( $l - $cr ) ) > $sl )
        {
            $ts = substr ( $s, $ns, ( $sl - $ns ) );
        }
        else
        {
            $ts = substr ( $s, $ns, ( $l - $cr ) );
        }

        for ( $x = ( strlen ( $ts ) - 1 ); $x >= 0; $x -= 1 )
        {
            $z = array ( "\t", "\r", "\n", " ", "\0", "\x0B" );

            if ( in_array ( $ts[$x], $z ) )
            {
                $rs .= substr ( $ts, 0, $x );

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rs . $e;
}

$truncate_text = 'This <img src="" alt=""> function works great however if a <a href="http://.com/page.html?test=1">html element</a> is found it will stop where the 45th character count is no matter what, which breaks the html element. How can I make an exception for this? I\'m guessing some kind of regex but not sure what is best in this case.';

//$truncate_text = 'This function works great however if a html element is found it will stop where the 45th character count is no matter what, which breaks the html element. How can I make an exception for this? I\'m guessing some kind of regex but not sure what is best in this case.';

$truncate_characters = 45;

$truncate_ending = '...';

echo truncate_by_characters ( $truncate_text, $truncate_characters, $truncate_ending );

?>
```

NOTE: The function above works however the function below does not produce any results at the moment.

this second one is to truncate @ number of words

```
<?php

function truncate_by_words ( $s, $l = 45, $e = '...' )
{
    $sl = strlen ( $s );

    $ns = 0;

    $tw = 0;

    $rs = '';

    preg_match_all ( '/<[^>]*>[^<]+<\/[^>]*>|<(?!\/)[^>]*>/', $s, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER );

    foreach ( $m as $v )
    {
        $ss = substr ( $s, $ns, ( $v[0][1] - $ns ) );

        $wf = str_word_count ( $ss, 2 );

        $wc = count ( $wf );

        if ( ( $tw + $wc ) >= $l )
        {
            $mw = 1;

            foreach ( $wf AS $wp => $wv )
            {
                if ( ( $tw + $mw++ ) == $l )
                {
                    $ss = substr ( $s, $ns, ( $wp - $ns ) );

                    $rs .= $ss . $wv;

                    $ns = ( $wp + strlen ( $wv ) );

                    $tw = $l;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $tw += $wc;

        $rs .= $ss . $v[0][0];

        $ns = ( $v[0][1] + strlen ( $v[0][0] ) );
    }

    if ( $tw < $l )
    {
        $ss = substr ( $s, $ns, ( $sl - $ns ) );

        $wf = str_word_count ( $ss, 2 );

        $wc = count ( $wf );

        if ( ( $tw + $wc ) <= $l )
        {
            $rs .= $ss;
        }
        else
        {
            $mw = 1;

            foreach ( $wf AS $wp => $wv )
            {
                if ( ( $tw + $mw++ ) == $l )
                {
                    $ss = substr ( $ss, 0, $wp );

                    $rs .= $ss . $wv;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $rs . $e;
}

$truncate_text = 'This <img src="" alt=""> function works great however if a <a href="http://.com/page.html?test=1">html element</a> is found it will stop where the 45th character count is no matter what, which breaks the html element. How can I make an exception for this? I\'m guessing some kind of regex but not sure what is best in this case.';

//$truncate_text = 'This function works great however if a html element is found it will stop where the 45th character count is no matter what, which breaks the html element. How can I make an exception for this? I\'m guessing some kind of regex but not sure what is best in this case.';

$truncate_words = 35;

$truncate_ending = '...';

echo truncate_by_words ( $truncate_text, $truncate_words, $truncate_ending );

?>
```

Comment: Nice, the first one for number of characters works great, however I would really like the words one to work if possible, right now the words function does not appear to work. Also can you consider tags like @foo_underscore otherwise the _underscore get left unlinked too. Thanks so much for your help here.

Comment: Just following up:)

Comment: @10826537 can you please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Use PHP `stript_tags()` (Easy option)
This will return plain text, any tags in the string will no longer work (i.e. `<a>, <strong>, <li>` etc. Implementation would look like:

```
$text = strip_tags($text);
```

2) Use the suggestion of @Chris Harrison here: [PHP limit text string NOT including html tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161634/php-limit-text-string-not-including-html-tags/8485989#answer-8485989)

This option keeps the tags, but would require you to rebuild your function to be more complex.

**UPDATE:**

This may not be what you're looking for, but I created a simple solution that breaks the string into chunks and then checks each chunk. It's not as precise as option 2, but it's a lot less code to maintain.

```
function truncate($string, $maxChars) {
    // Explode input string on a character
    $stringParts = explode(' ', $string);
    $finalString = '';
    $charCount = 0;
    foreach ($stringParts as $part) {
        if ($charCount <= $maxChars) {
            $charCount += strlen(strip_tags($part));
            $finalString .= (' ' . $part);
        } else {
            return $finalString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think #2 is the answer for me, I’ll check it and get back to ya.

Comment: The string is dynamic and could contain any number of links, so ideally I need something for, if it finds a link before stopping make sure to include the rest of the link before stopping, none of your solutions are working for me unfortunately.